# Vue select, pre-selected options

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have two instances of a Vue select, which work perfectly. One is being filled with hard-coded options, the other is being filled via axios return object, but both are properly filling with options in the for loop.

My only remaining issue, is I'm having a hard time getting them to load a default pre-selected option. Say I want `taskTypes` to be loaded by default with value 3 and `taskLocations` to be pre selected with value 10, I'm having a hard time finding a way that does this in Vue

I've tried setting taskLocations.value in the return and the same for types but it doesn't load any value

```
<div class="form-group col-lg-6">
    <label>Locations</label>
    <select class="form-control" v-model="taskLocations" id="taskLocations" @change="handleLocationSelect">
      <option v-for="locationOption in locationOptions" v-bind:value="locationOption.id">{{ locationOption.name }}</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group col-lg-3">
    <label>Choose Task Type</label>
    <select class="form-control" v-model="taskTypes" id="taskTypes" @change="handleTypeSelect">
     <option v-for="taskTypeOption in taskTypeOptions" v-bind:value="taskTypeOption.value">{{ taskTypeOption.name }}</option>
    </select>
</div>

  locationOptions: [],
  taskLocations: [],
  taskTypes: []
  taskTypeOptions: [
    {value:1, name:"PM"},
    {value:2, name:"OD"},
    {value:3, name:"All"}

  ],
```

Comment: You can add 10 to the `taskLocations` array and 3 to the `taskTypes` array

Comment: Maybe I'm doing it wrong but just doing ```taskTypes: [3]``` doesn't do anything @ThomasvanBroekhoven

Comment: My bad, you should just do: `taskTypes: 3`. Since it is a input select element, you can only select one. If you want to use multiple select, you should consider using checkboxes. Hope this helps!